# how to retrieve bill pay transactions using yodlee rest api

Tags: yodlee

I using the executeUserSearchRequest to get transactions for bank,credit etc.
But I'm not able to get Bill Pay transactions.
Should I not be using this method to retrieve the lines, or perhaps I'm doing the search wrong. I know the account I'm using does contain lines as I've verified using another application that uses the yodlee api;s.

I using these settings
ContainerType: All
SplitType : ALL_TRANSACTION
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier = 9999999

where 99999 is the itemaccountid
all other values are defaults from the API testing tool
https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve transactions for billpay using the same API i.e., executeUserSearchRequest. Please remove itemAccountId.identifier and try to get transactions, it will return transactions for all accounts.

You can then verify is transactions for your billpay account is present or not.

If you want transactions for specific account then you can first call [getItemSummariesForSite](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesForSite) API to get the account level details for the added account and from there you can use the itemAccountId and pass it on to executeUserSearchRequest API.

If you still face any problem, please share your memSiteAccId over our chat support and we will be able to help you.